# Remove duplicates in the array, using TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Hi I have an array that has the same UserId and I want to delete the ones that are similar and keep only one
How do I do this?

Example:

```
a=[
{userId:1,name:''},
{userId:2,name:''},
{userId:3,name:''},
{userId:1,name:''},
{userId:1,name:''}
]
```

Conversion:

```
a=[
{userId:1,name:''},
{userId:2,name:''},
{userId:3,name:''}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use filter:

```js
    a.filter((item, index, array) => {
        const firstItemIndex = array.findIndex(innerItem => item.userId === innerItem.userId);
        return firstItemIndex === index;
    })
```

findIndex will always return the index of the first element it finds. It will then ignore the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend lodash uniqBy function https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#uniqBy

```
this.a = _.uniqBy(a, 'id');
```

Answer (score 0):

Performance should be better with this kind of code:

```
const keys = new Set<number>()
const result = []
for (const item of a) {
    if (!keys.has(item.userId)) {
        keys.add(item.userId)
        result.push(item)
    }
}
```